# Find minimum distance of the code

Tags: coding-theory

I want to show that the minimum distance of a narrow-sense  BCH code over $\mathbb{F}_q$ with length $n$ and designed distance $\delta$ is equal to $\delta$  provided that it holds that $\delta \mid n$.

It holds that a BCH code with designed distance $\delta$ has minimum distance
at least $\delta$.

So we need to show that there is a codeword with Hamming weight $\delta$.

How do  we deduce the existence of such a codeword from the fact that $\delta \mid n$ ?

Can we consider that the length of the code is of the form $q^m-1$ ?

If so, then we could use the fact that a $q$-ary bch code of length $q^m-1$ with designed distance $\delta$ has dimension at least $q^m-1-m(\delta-1)$, couldn't we?

Then from the sphere packing bound and the above proposition we get that $\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{d-1}{2} \rfloor} \binom{n}{i}(q-1)^i \leq q^{m(\delta-1)}$.

But does this help?

Or isn't the idea right?

Comment: By the way, this and your previous questions contains in http://store.elsevier.com/The-Theory-of-Error-Correcting-Codes/F_J_-MacWilliams/isbn-9780444851932/

Comment: @Mr.Newman Is there maybe also an online version?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find english edition (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Peterson** theorem: if $n=\delta b$, then the distance of narrow-sense BCH with designed distance $\delta$ is equal to $\delta$

**Proof**: Let $\alpha$ has the order $n$ and $\alpha,\alpha^2,...,\alpha^r$ is a BCH-chain for $r=\delta-1$. Not hard to see
$$x^n-1=(x^b-1)(1+x^b+...+x^{rb}).$$
Since $\alpha^{ib}\ne1$ for $i=1,...,r$ then all of chain elements are roots of $h(x)=1+x^b+...+x^{rb}$. So, $h(x)$ is a word of weight $\delta$.

Comment: What do you mean with BCH-chain? $$$$
Do you mean the sequence of powers of $\alpha$ such that $c(\alpha^b)=c(\alpha^{b+1})=\dots+ c(\alpha^{b+\delta-2})=0$ if $c$ is a codeword?

Comment: I mean by  "BCH-chain" the chain of elements $\alpha,\alpha^2,...,\alpha^r$ from which we construct the code. Since $h(\alpha)=h(\alpha^2)=...=h(\alpha^r)=0$ then $h(x)$ is a codeword

Comment: Is $h$ a word of weight $\delta$ since it has $\delta$ roots? $$$$
If so, we know that it holds that $$ c(x) \in C \Leftrightarrow c(\alpha^b)=c(\alpha^{b+1})=\dots=c(\alpha^{b+\delta-2})=0$$

Wouldn't this mean that all the words of a BCH code have Hamming weight $\delta$ ? Or am I wrong?

Comment: How to construct  BCH code of the length $n$ over the field $GF(q)$ with designed distance $r$. We have to choose

1) $Q=GF(q^l)$ an extension of the field $GF(p)$

2) $\alpha\in Q$ an element of order $n$

3) a system $\alpha^s,\alpha^{s+1},...,\alpha^{s+r-1}$ (chain)

Further, $g(x)$ be a minimal polynomial which annihilate any of $\alpha^i$. So, the cyclic code over $P$ with generating polynomial $g(x)$ is our BCH-code. Your case is **narrow-sense**, i.e. $s=1$. Any of codewords $c(x)$ can be represented in the form
$$c(x)=g(x)t(x)(\mathrm{mod\ }(x^n-1))$$

Comment: So $h(x)$ is word of weight $\delta$ since weight of $(h_r,...,h_1,h_0)=(1,...,1,1)$ is equal to $\delta$. So any of codewords $c(x)$ should have at least $\delta$ roots but it's weight can be greater than $\delta$

Comment: Shouldn't $c(x)$ have at least $\delta-1$ roots? Since the powers of $\alpha$ are consecutive, how can it be that the weight is greater than $\delta$ ? Could you give me such an example where there are $\delta-1$ roots but the weight is greater than $\delta$ ? @Mr.Newman

Comment: Sorry, misprint. Of course, any codeword should have at least $\delta-1$ roots.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Could you explain to me how it can be that there are $\delta-1$ roots and the weight is greater than $\delta$ ?

Comment: $h(x)=x^{rb}+...+x^b+1$ is the codeword, so if $b>1$ then the codeword $(x-1)h(x)(\mathrm{mod\ }(x^n-1))=x^{rb+1}-x^{rb}-...+x^{b+1}-x^b+x-1$ has the same set of roots (plus $1$) but its weight is $2\delta$

Comment: Ah I see... Thank you!!! Are you familiar with Reed-Solomon codes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39067/discussion-between-mr-newman-and-evinda).

Comment: Hey $$$$
Could I maybe also ask you something else?